# A Replay Attack was Detected (4649) on DC and File Server - How should I investigate this?

Tags: exploit

Just as the title states. We've had an alert for a replay attack being detected, how would I investigate this? It's the first alert of this type I've seen, so I'm unsure how to proceed.

Comment: Was the attack successful? If so, the reason might be that there is no/insufficient forward secrecy in the crypto scheme used. Normally, updating to a secure protocol version would fix that.

Comment: potential duplicate, but the answer might not suffice: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/194223/a-replay-attack-was-detected-4649-exchange-healthmailbox

Answer (score 1):

I snagged this potential answer from Reddit which linked to an article at ITProToday:

> ”When the Kerberos logic on a DC or resource server
>   validates a Kerberos authentication message, it will always check the
>   authenticator's timestamp. If the timestamp is earlier or the same as
>   a previous authenticator, the server-side Kerberos logic will reject
>   the packet because it considers it part of a replay attack and user
>   authentication will fail. The Kerberos server-side logic also compares
>   the timestamp in the authenticator to the local server time. If the
>   timestamp in the authenticator isn't within five minutes of the time
>   on the server, it will also reject the packet. These five minutes are
>   referred to as the Kerberos time skew.”
>
> I would start by having the local time checked on that remote host.
>   Then any issues on the vpn infra. Apparently this type of attack
>   grants nothing for the attacker so it most likely is not an attacker
>   but a misconfiguration.

https://www.itprotoday.com/security/understanding-how-kerberos-authentication-protects-against-replay-attacks

So, your first step should be to determine if this is a "true positive" by ruling out potential configuration issues while also analyzing your Domain Controller logs.